# Access 2010 linked ODBC table missing column issue

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012

Bit of a weird one here, but we have several SQL Server views which are linked ODBC tables in an Access 2003 (mdb) database being opened in Access 2010, but I can confirm that the same problem exists in Access 2010 (accdb) databases. SQL Server version is 2012. The connection to SQL Server is through a system ODBC link.

In ViewA and ViewB defintions on SQL Server, we have [Date_Last_Sunday], [Date_Next_Monday], [Date_Next_Sunday], [Date_2_Mondays_Future] and a few others. Both views have the exact same date columns, but have different columns to the left. In SSMS both queries return the exact same date columns without issue. I can also confirm that there are no duplicate column names in either of them.

When I link ViewA into Access and open it up to check everything, I see this:
[image]

When I link ViewB into Access and do the same check, I see this:
[image]

Notice how the [Date_Next_Monday] column is missing, however the data is still there, but in the wrong columns! I can't really come up with an explanation better than some kind of Jet bug, but it's extremely strange. This has been working for years and has just been reported as an issue today.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Does the behaviour persist if you drop and re-create the ODBC linked tables that point to the views?

Comment: Carefully check object names and even versions. You might be pointing to another table/view or another db on server and renamed in Access.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes it does persist. I dropped and recreated the ODBC link itself, plus both tables, relinked them, exact same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother everyone with this one, I feel a bit stupid now that I figured it out!!

The problem stemmed from the fact that there was a third view which returns the dates (call it ViewDates), which was used by both ViewA and ViewB. In both views, I did a cross join with ViewDates and in the `SELECT` list, added `ViewDates.*`. ViewDates must have been modified after ViewB was already created.

I did a bit more testing and observed the strange behaviour on SQL Server in SSMS after running `SELECT * FROM ViewB` but when I scripted ViewB out and selected the query to run it, the results had the correct data. Before I posted, I had originally scripted it out and run it, which made me think the problem was with Access when it was actually with SQL Server.

All that was required in the end to solve this was scripting out the ViewB and execute (recompiling it).

I still find it very strange that the data would persist despite the column not being recognised! I guess that's what happens when you build views on top of views on top of views...

I suppose I have to bear in mind that these were the very first views I had ever written, so I can excuse myself for violating all of the good design practices I've learned since then.

Comment: Funny things happen in Access when a SQL view is changed and the data isn't refreshed.  That's always the first response, similar to when every Help Desk person tells you to reboot.  It fixes the vast majority of problems.